# Поймать GET и сравнить со значением в массиве

Tags: php, массивы, get, сравнение

Всем привет.
Ловлю utm метку к примеру такую ?utm_term=Игрушки в городе Пушкино

Дальше у меня есть такой массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Message_ID] => 1
            [Title] => Пушкино
            [Morphy] => Пушкино // игрушки в Пушкино
            [Term] => пушкино // слова которые могу встретиться в utm_term
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Message_ID] => 2
            [Title] => Броницы
            [Morphy] => Броницах // игрушки в Броницах
            [Term] => броницы,броницах // слова которые могу встретиться в utm_term
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Message_ID] => 3
            [Title] => Воскресенск
            [Morphy] => Воскресенске // игрушки в Воскресенске
            [Term] => воскресенск,воскресенске // слова которые могу встретиться в utm_term
        )
)
```

Суть utm_term сравнить с тем, что в [Term] и если есть совпадения вывести [Morphy].

```
$UtmTerm = htmlspecialchars($_GET["utm_term"]); - ловим utm_term
$UtmTerm = mb_strtolower($UtmTerm); - привидом все нижний регистр
$UtmTermArray = explode(" ", $UtmTerm); - разбираем на массив
```

получаю 
Array ( [0] => игрушки [1] => в [2] => городе [2] => пушкино )

```
foreach($var as $k => $v) {
   $res = array_intersect(explode(",", $v[Term]), $UtmTermArray); // сравниваем получившиеся массивы
   if (!empty($res)) {
       print_r($res);
   }
}
```

Получаю Array ( [1] => пушкино )  - это то, что в array [Term]

Но как мне вывести не то, что в [Term], а то что [Morphy], т.к. в Morphy - склоненный город.

И вообще может у меня не правильный подход к задаче, посоветуйте может как, что переделать стоит?

Comment: а если в `array_intersect` прописать просто `$v`, а не `$v[Term]` не решается проблема?

Comment: нет, http://joxi.ru/Q2K5xdDS4nqJ7r или какой то другой подход придумать.

Comment: тогда вам нужно для найденного совпадению сохранять ключ элемента у которого есть совпадение и выводить Morphy по этому ключу из нужного массива, а для этого лучше всего подойдет array_search поскольку он вернет вам как раз ключ в искомом массиве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$search = 'Игрушки в городе Пушкино';
$data = [
     [
          'Message_ID' => 1,
          'Title' => 'Пушкино',
          'Morphy' => 'Пушкино', 
          'Term' => 'пушкино',
     ],
     [
          'Message_ID' => 2,
          'Title' => 'Броницы',
          'Morphy' => 'Броницы', 
          'Term' => 'броницы,броницах',
     ],
     [
          'Message_ID' => 3,
          'Title' => 'Воскресенск',
          'Morphy' => 'Воскресенск',
          'Term' => 'воскресенск,воскресенске',
     ],
];
$relativeSearch = [];

foreach($data as $row){
    $terms = explode(',', $row['Term']);

    foreach($terms as $term){
        similar_text($search, $term, $perc);
        $relativeSearch[$perc] = $row;
    }
}

krsort($relativeSearch);
print_r(reset($relativeSearch));
```

А вообще думаю есть смысл посмотреть в сторону поисковых движков вроде Sphinx

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sphinx.php

Comment: Спасибо, почти тоже самое мне тут https://toster.ru/q/548900 написали.

Comment: через **array_intersect** ищет полное соответсвие слова, у меня самое похожее. Тоесть варианты с `Пушкин` и `Воскресенье` тоже выдадут результаты без необходимости перечислять все возможные вариации

Comment: хорошо, учту...